# Compress log files when using SiftingAppender of Logback

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, logback-classic

I know it is possible to compress log files with FixedWindowRollingPolicy or TimeBasedRollingPolicy of the RollingFileAppender. However, I was wondering if compression is possible when using just a SiftingAppender. My current configuration is as following:

```xml
    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">

        <discriminator>
            <key>id</key>
            <defaultValue>-</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>

        <sift>
            <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${DEV_HOME}/${date}/server-${id}.log</file>
                <append>true</append>

                <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%-30.30logger{30}] [%thread] [%-8X{id}] - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>

            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
```

I tried adding .zip and .gz at the end of the file name and while it does create a compressed file, the created file cannot be opened. I was wondering if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to post an update. It is not possible to compress files using the SiftingAppender. To meet my goal, I used the `@Scheduled` annotation of Spring Boot to create a task to perform zipping and clean up according to a cron expression.

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * *")
private void backupAndPurgeLogs() {}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: To add another comment, I discovered it is possible to use RollingFileAppender within the SiftingAppender. RollingFileAppender does support zipping of log files as they are created so that option is available. I wanted to compress my log files after a week which is why I took the above approach.